# SwiftUI - Conflicting arguments to generic parameter in List and ForEach

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm encountering conflicting arguments to generic parameter errors in SwiftUI, specifically in the List and ForEach components. Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
// SeasonDetailsView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct SeasonDetailsView: View {
    var season: DataManager.DataManagerSeason

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(season.games, id: \.id) { game in
                Section(header: Text("Game on \(game.date)")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: GameDetailsView(game: game)) {
                        Text("Details for \(game.date)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(season.name)
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

For the List component:

"Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'Content' ('<>' vs. '<>' vs. '<>' vs. '<>')"

For the ForEach component:

`Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'Content' ('<<hole>>' vs. '<<hole>>' vs. '<<hole>>' vs. '<<hole>>')`

`Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'Content' ('ForEach<[DataManager.DataManagerGame], UUID, <<hole>>>' vs. 'ForEach<[DataManager.DataManagerGame], UUID, <<hole>>>')`

For the .navigationBarTitle modifier:

`Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'Self' ('List<Never, <<hole>>>' vs. 'List<Never, <<hole>>>)`

I attempted to implement a SwiftUI List and ForEach structure in my SeasonDetailsView.swift file. The goal was to display a list of games with associated details. I also experimented with using a Section to organize the games and using a Vstack as an alternative.
I expected the code to compile successfully and display a list of games, each with a clickable link to the GameDetailsView. The navigationBarTitle was intended to reflect the current season's name.
The code encountered conflicting generic parameter errors, particularly related to the usage of List, ForEach, and navigationBarTitle. Despite multiple attempts to rectify the issue, the errors persisted, leading to difficulty in achieving the intended layout.

Comment: Check your GameDetzilView : it may not return a valid View conforming object. Note that NavigationLink with destination view create the destination view.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example (i.e. we need to know what;s in season.games and GameDetailsView). Typically such errors are a side effect of some fundamental problem with either data or one of the views. To debug, first comment out `ForEach`. If that passes compilation,  uncomment ForEach and Section, but leave NavigationLink commented out. And so on